# Struggling with a warning I am receiving when trying to run my MATLAB function.. The error that comes up is "

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

Struggling with a warning I am receiving when trying to run my MATLAB function.. The error that comes up is

> "Warning: Failure at t=3.107182e-03.  Unable to meet integration tolerances without reducing the
>   step size below the smallest value allowed (6.938894e-18) at time t. In ode15s (line 730)"

I know I have to find the singularity in the function, but I am not sure how to enable myself to view the ode values that were able to compile prior to the error. 
Anyone know how to view the values? My code is the following:

```
function EMatlabModel()
 % Define constants
 H = 0.04; %[m] Height between cathode and anode
 D = 0.000399; %[m^2/s] diffusion
 F = 96485.3329; %[C] Faraday's constant
 z = 1; % charge of gold
 r = 0.02; %[m] radius of space between electrodes
 m = 1; % mobility of gold
 R = 0.008314; %[J/molK] - divded by 1000 to ensure correct units
 T = 360.65; %[K] temperature of cell
 nY = 99; % Number of interior nodes (y direction)
 dY = (H - 0)/(nY + 1); % Node spacing (y direction)
 tspan = [0 H];
 Co = 0.01*ones(nY+1,1);

% Integrate discretized ODEs using ode15s
sol = ode15s(@funcs,tspan,Co)

% Plot the results
x = linspace(0.15,0.95,5);
el = deval(x,sol)
plot(x,el)
colormap hsv
colorbar
xlabel('Length Away from Cathode');
ylabel('Concentration of Gold');

 %------------------------------------------------------------
 % Define functions to be integrated in x.
 %------------------------------------------------------------
function res = funcs(x,y) % where y = C
    res=zeros(nY+1,1);

    %u = 1e-10;
    um = 0.04;
    Cin = 0.01;
    Vin = 5 + 2.037;

     res(1) = D/dY^2*(y(2) - 2*y(1) + Cin)+ ...
         D/z/dY^2*(y(2) - 2*y(1) + Cin) + ...
         y(1)*um*2*(abs(y(1) - r/2)/r^2) + D*y(1)*F*z*m*Vin/(R*T*H);

      for j = 2:nY
         %ux(j) = um*(1 - abs(y(j) - r/2)/r);
         res(j) = D/dY^2*(y(j+1) - 2*y(j) + y(j-1)) +... 
             + D/z/dY^2*(y(j+1) - 2*y(j) + y(j-1)) + ...
             y(j)*um*2*(abs(y(j) - r/2)/r^2) + D*y(j)*F*z*m*Vin/(R*T*H);
      end
  end
 end
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: just posted in the question!

Comment: Look in the [documentation for `ode15s`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode15s.html#inputarg_options) at the `options` input. You can set a looser tolerance, or output solutions as the solver progresses.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment but to put your solution definitely diverges that's why you are getting that error, you need to play around with `tspan` and limit it further

Comment: this still doesn't seem to be working for some reason, even with an extravagantly varied tspan.. any thoughts?

Comment: from my experience in using it it should be just a small range and certain range just works better than other. i can only reason this to the random processes used in the algorithm.